# How to get current date birthday's list using MySQL query

Tags: mysql

i have around 50 years of data.how can i found current day birthday list using MySQL query.i tried a lot using some query but i found duplicate

> SELECT * FROM member where DATE_FORMAT((),'%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%m-%d');

above code is getting duplicate

Comment: What is `DATE_FORMAT((),'%m-%d')`?  I don't think will even compile.  Please add some sample data to your question.

Comment: id  dateofbirth
1 1992-03-21
2   1993-03-21
3   1982-03-21

Comment: Looks fine except for changing it to `DATE_FORMAT(birthday,'%m-%d')`. What are the duplicates you are getting with your sample data?

Comment: id are showing duplicate.if possible please provide a query which shows exact current birthday list from years of data

Comment: The only explanation I can come up with is that your IDs are not unique.

Answer (score 0):

You can use month() and day() function from the mysql. But you will need to cast for both data column and also the argument

select * from member where month(dateofbirth) = month(now()) and day(dateofbirth) = day(now())

Comment: Thanks. I used                           select * from member where month(dateofbirth) = month(now()) and day(dateofbirth) = day(now())       this query but not getting proper data.Data is missmatching

Comment: Your problem is duplicate id displayed?. If that so,first you should look at the data you stored was it correct or not. If no choice, you can do this
select distinct id from member where month(dateofbirth) = month(now()) and day(dateofbirth) = day(now())